# Dealing with Spaces and NA's when Uniting Multiple Columns with Tidyr

Tags: regex, r, tidyr

So using the simple dataframe below, I want to create a new column that has all the days for each person, separated by a semi-colon.

For example, using Doug, it should look like - Monday; Wednesday; Friday

I would like to use Tidyr's Unite function for this but when I use it, I get - Monday;;Wednesday;;Friday, because of the NA's, which also could be blank spaces as well. Sometimes there are semi-colons at the beginning and end as well. So I'm hoping there's a way to keep using "unite" but enhanced with a regular expression so that I end up with each day of the week separated by one semi-colon, and no semi-colons at the beginning or end.

I would also like to stick with Tidyr, Dplyr, Stringr, etc.

```
Names<-c("Doug","Ken","Erin","Yuki","John")
Monday<-c("Monday"," "," ","Monday","Monday")
Tuesday<-c(" ","Tuesday","Tuesday"," ","Tuesday")
Wednesday<-c(" ","Wednesday","Wednesday","Wednesday"," ")
Thursday<-c(" "," "," "," ","Thursday")
Friday<-c(" "," "," "," ","Friday")

Days<-data.frame(Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday)

 Days<-Days%>%unite(BestDays,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,sep="; ",remove=FALSE)
```

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/issues/203

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `getAnywhere("unite_.data.frame")`, unite is calling `do.call("paste", c(data[from], list(sep = sep)))` underhood, and `paste` as far as I know doesn't provide a functionality to omit NAs unless manually implemented in some way;

Nevertheless, you can use a regular expression method as follows with `gsub` from base R to clean up the result column:

```
gsub("^\\s;\\s|;\\s{2}", "", Days$BestDays)
# [1] "Monday"                            "Tuesday; Wednesday"               
# [3] "Tuesday; Wednesday"                "Monday; Wednesday"                
# [5] "Monday; Tuesday; Thursday; Friday"
```

This removes either `^\\s;\\s` pattern or `;\\s{2}` pattern, the former handle the case when the string starts with space string where we can just remove the space and it's following `;\\s`, otherwise remove `;\\s{2}` which can handle cases where `\\s` are both in the middle of the string and at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Psidom, but it doesn't seem to work when I try it. Perhaps it's because the NA's aren't actually in the final result. Instead, it looks like (See continuation below...)

Comment: ;Monday;;Wednesday;Friday or Monday;;Wednesday;Friday;  etc...So I need a regular expression to remove all instances of a semi-colon at the beginning or end, as well as instances of double semi-colons, such as ;;  I also need to incorporate gsub into a mutate call with dplyr for the dataframe.

Comment: Hi again. I realize it didn't work because the dataset that I'm actually working on had spaces instead of NA's, so that explains it. So that's why the examples in the above comment just have semi-colons instead of NA's. My fault. I can accept your answer above and create a new question if you prefer, otherwise it would be great if you could show me the gsub with regex for spaces instead of NA's.

Comment: I edited the reproducible example code to better reflect the actual data I'm working with...

Comment: You can just replace `NA` with space `\\s` and it should work. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work on the example I provided. I also tried this method to just remove leading and trailing semi-colons, as well as well as instances of a semi-colon followed by another semi-colon, but it doesn't seem to work.                                                                     Days<-Days%>%mutate(gsub("^;*|(?<=;)|;*$", "", Days$BestDays))

Comment: You need to specify `perl=TRUE` when you use look behind syntax. Also you are missing a `;`, otherwise, I think your regex is fine. `gsub("^;*|(?<=;);|;*$", "", s, perl = T)`

Comment: Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
Names<-c("Doug","Ken","Erin","Yuki","John")
Monday<-c("Monday",NA,NA,"Monday","Monday")
Tuesday<-c(NA,"Tuesday","Tuesday",NA,"Tuesday")
Wednesday<-c(NA,"Wednesday","Wednesday","Wednesday",NA)
Thursday<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"Thursday")
Friday<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"Friday")

Days<-data.frame(Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday)

concat_str = function(str) str %>% na.omit %>% paste(collapse = "; ")
Days$BestDaysConcat = apply(Days[,c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday")], 1, concat_str)
```